# Calculate the fullness of an apartment using SQL expression

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which looks like this:

Reservations Table:

```
-------------------------------------------------
id   |   room_id  |     start     |     end     | 
 1   |      1     |   2015-05-13  |  2015-05-16 |
 2   |      1     |   2015-05-18  |  2015-05-20 |
 3   |      1     |   2015-05-21  |  2015-05-24 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Apartment Table:

```
---------------------------------------
id   |   room_id  |     name          |
 1   |      1     |   test apartment  |
---------------------------------------
```

Meaning that in the month 05 (May) there is 31 days in the database we have 3 events giving us 8 days of usage 31 - 8 = 23 / 31 = 0.741 * 100 = %74.1 is the percentage of the emptiness and %25.9 is the percentage of usage. how can i do all of that in SQL? (mySQL).

Comment: Where in your table is aparment_id?

Comment: Can the month change between start and end?

Comment: @Reversal yes, but i would need just like the basic idea of making such calc so i can adjust it later. lad the apartment doesn't really matter i explained what i need

Answer (score 0):

This is my proposal:

```
SELECT SUM(DAY(`end`)-DAY(`start`))/EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(`start`)) FROM `apt`;
```

[`LAST_DAY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function gives as output the date of last day of the month.

Comment: Please see i have added the properties table so can we do something that will calculate the fullness of the apartment of all times i mean count all the reservations records per apartment.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c53b/2/0

Not the most efficient query but will get the job done.

```
select 
sum(a.days)*100/(SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(min(start))) from test1) 
   as usePercent,
100-(sum(a.days)*100/(SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(min(start))) from test1)) 
   as emptyPercent
FROM 
(select DATEDIFF(end,start) as days from test1) a
```

What I did is first get the date difference and count them. Then in a nested query use the day(last_day()) function to get the last day of month. Then calculated by using your logic.